# Components of Compund Glyphs in OpenType/TrueType

Tags: fonts, truetype, typography, opentype

I cannot find any information in the specification for the [OpenType](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/glyf.htm)/[TrueType](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM06/Chap6glyf.html) *glyf* table that clarifies if the components of a compound glyph are always simple glyphs, or if they can be compound glyphs themselves (i.e. recursive compound glyphs).

Since the specification does not explicitly prohibit compound glyphs as components, I would assume that it is possible in theory. But my question is: Are there any fonts that actually contain recursive compound glyphs? And do any of the major font tools support this?

The background is that I am writing a simple font parser and I want to know if I need to be aware of recursive compound glyphs, because this would make the algorithms a bit more complicated.

**Update:** I found some information in the spec for the [maxp table](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM06/Chap6maxp.html). This defines *maxComponentDepth*, which is the maximum level of recursions for compound glyphs. This shows me that recursive compound glyphs are possible. But are they actually being used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that in the standard Arial font there are four compound glyphs that have another compound glyph as a component. One example is the glyph at index 471, which is used for unicode U+01FB (latin small letter a with ring above and acute). It consists of the Acute glyph, which is a simple glyph, and the small latin a with ring above, which is a compound glyph.

Composition of glyph 471 in TrueType font Arial:

[image: composition of glyph 471]

So the conclusions from this are:

1. Recursivly compound glyphs are possible in TrueType/OpenType fonts.
2. These glyphs exist in common fonts.

Comment: Nice research! I was wondering the same myself. BTW, how is your parser going?